# Different dialogues for inner thoughts

Tags: dialogue

Whenever I write inner thoughts I do something like:

*What is she thinking?*, Maria thought.

I find myself using the word thought, think, or wonder a lot when writing inner thoughts. Is there a way to write their inner thoughts without using dialogue tags?

Answer (score 1):

I just use italics for writing thoughts, and maybe use dialogue tags every now and then to make it clear it's thoughts. I think it's mostly understood that italics are thoughts, so you could probably get away with no tags whatsoever if you really wanted to.

Comment: Yeah, I think you can definitely get away with it. And depending on your perspective, you can often drop the italics as well.

Comment: Yeah, I use italics too, although I put the italics in quotes just to make it very clear.